# Facing Error during deployment of an SSIS Package

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2012

**Objective:** To Create a job and deploy SSIS Package with a configuration file.

**ERROR**
Executed as user: User\SYSTEM. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility Version 13.0.5888.11 for 64bit Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft. All rights reserved. Started 7:29:06 PM Error:2022-07-12 19:29:06.37 Code 0xC0016016
Source: SourceOne  Description: Failed to decrypt protected XML node "DTS:Password" with error 0x8009000B "Key not valid for use in specified state." You may not be authorized to access this information. This error occurs when there is a cryptographic error.
Verify that the correct key is available. End Error  Error: 2022-07-12 19:29:06.45 Code: 0xC0202009  Source:SourceOne Connection manager "Destination" Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occured.
Error code: 0x80040E4D. An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server" Hresult: 0x80040E4D Description: "Login failed for user 'UserOne'". End Error  Error:2022-07-12 19:29:06.45 Code:0xC020801C: Source To Dest Lookup[2]
Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER. The AcquireConnection method call to connection manager "Destination" failed with error code 0xC0202009.
There may ne error message posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed. End Error  Error:2022-07-12 19:29:06.45 Code: 0xC0047017  Source: Source To Dest SSIS Pipeline
Description: Lookup failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C. End Error  Error:2022-07-12 19:29:06.45  Code:0xC004700C Source: Source To Dest SSIS Pipeline  Description: One or more component failed validation. End Error  Error: 2022-07-12 19:29:06.45
Code: 0xC0024107  Source: Source To Dest  Description: There were errors during task validation. End Error DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_Failure(1). Started: 7:29:06 PM finished 7:29:06 PM Elapsed: 0.156 seconds. The package execution failed. The step failed.

**My Source is Windows Authentication and Destination is SQL Server**

**To Resolve: I tried Delay Validation = True and Protection Level: DontSaveSensitive**
But after that i am getting error in Visual Studio while running package

**ERROR:**
[Lookup[2]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONMANAGER. The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Destination" failed with error code 0xC0202009.
There may be error message posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method Call failed.

[SSIS.Pipeline] Error:Lookup failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error:One or more component failed validation.
[Connection manager "Destination"] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occured. Error code: 0x80040E4D.
An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server" Hresult:0x80040E4D Description: "Login failed for user 'UserOne'.".

Comment: It looks like you've provided the error you received *before* changing the protection level to "DontSaveSensitive". The error provided typically happens when protection level is "encrypt sensitive with user key" and then you attempt to deploy as a different user. It looks like you have not provided the error you get when protection level is set to "don't save sensitive" ("the destination connection broke out" is not a real error message that we can use to help diagnose the problem).

Comment: By changing protection level to "don't save sensitive" the package did exactly that... so the password is no longer saved in the package. It has to be provided another way, for example from the config file. It looks like the password either is not being provided, or the provided password is not correct. Tangentially, I would suggest moving to the project deployment model if you can. SSIS configuration is *much* nicer.

Comment: @allmhuran Thanks a lot! Issues has been resolved.

Tell me one more thing is it possible to deploy SSIS Package with config file on server for example xxx.xxx.xx.21 which is Destination also(SQL Server Authentication)  and source is different for example xxx.xxx.xx.46(Windows Authentication)

Comment: The deployed location of the config file, and the deployed location of the SSIS package itself, is unrelated to whatever sources and destinations you have in your dataflows inside the package.